# git master branch is crazy

Tags: git, github

I was looking into a project with qgit tool, and for "no reason" (ok, it was probably me) the master branch got down to the beginning of project.

It is now

[image: master branch is down there]

I have a backup to show how it should be.

[image: master branch in its original location]

I can restore the backup to make everything work again (also this project is just an finished exercise, not work, not important), but I want to know what happened here. And, if possible, to restore the initial flow again.

One more thing. I first created the project in github, at same time I started the project locally with `git init`, committed and pushed (without fetching). That's why commits 2 and 3 are unrelated.

Comment: This is your local branch master that move so no panic, just `git checkout master` then `git reset --hard github/master`

Comment: It worked. I didn't know I could move a branch (except for rebase, but I'm sure I didn't do it).

Comment: please, try to use more compelling titles next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have move your local `master` branch to same commit as `github/main`

If you want your local `master` branch pointing to the same commit than your `master` branch on github

Checkout on your local master branch:

`git checkout master`

then

`git reset --hard github/master`